# How to extend LatLng

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I wrote a code to draw a path from gpx file. If the user turns the smartphone, the path is cleared, then I created a `ArrayList<MyLatLng>` where every `MyLatLng` object is:

```
public class MyLatLng implements Parcelable {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public MyLatLng(double lat, double lon) {
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int arg) {
        parcel.writeDouble(latitude);
        parcel.writeDouble(longitude);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyLatLng> CREATOR = new Creator<MyLatLng>() {
        @Override
        public MyLatLng createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            double latitude = parcel.readDouble();
            double longitude = parcel.readInt();
            return new MyLatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public MyLatLng[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyLatLng[size];
        }
    };

    //Metodi get/set

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

And using `onSaveInstanceState` I avoid the cancellation of the path. But this method introduces a non-elegance in my code because every time I need to create a `LatLng` object from `MyLatLng` object. Do you have any advice about this? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can't you just use `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`? It's `Parcelable`, too.

Comment: Can this work with ArrayList<LatLng> ? outState.putParcelableArrayList("path", mLatLngGpxList); Where mLatLngGpxList is an ArrayList<LatLng> ???